# Why does the iMac charge my iPhone faster than the wall charger?

Tags: iphone, imac, usb, charging

I've noticed that my iMac at work (21.5", Mid 2011) charges my iPhone 5 about 2-3x faster than the included wall charger.

How does it do that?

Comment: read the information on the charger!

Comment: @Buscar웃 I believe it delivers 5V at 1A. I haven't been able to find what the Mac does, so I'm asking here.

Comment: 5V and 0.5 A or 1A USB, depends

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the [USB 3 SuperSpeed](http://www.neowin.net/news/say-goodbye-to-power-cords-with-usb-30-update) (on your Mac) it can deliver up to 100 Watts.

For iPhone it will deliver 10 Watts (5 Volt x 2 Amps) which is more than your charger.

Comment: Thanks, I was trying not to ask a shopping question.

Comment: @Ruskes Does this fast charging effect the iphone battery?